# How can I convert ListBox-Items into integer?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Actually I'm working in MFC-framework and I want to create an array, that has to be sorted.

I've already created an array and printed these numbers into listBox as elements, but now I want to reconvert them into integer to swap them.

How can I do this?

Here some code:

```
void CSortMFC1Dlg::exchange(int& a, int& b) {
    int c;

    c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
}

void CSortMFC1Dlg::OnBnClickedSortBubble()
{
    UpdateData(true);

    for (int j = 0; j < (SIZE - 1); ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (SIZE - 1); ++i) {
            if (myArray[i] > myArray[i + 1]) {
                //exchange(myArray[i], myArray[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    UpdateData(false);
}
```

Comment: Horrible sort.  Just use `std::sort(myArray, myArray + SIZE);`

Comment: that was not my question,...

Comment: I guess you are not aware of what the comment section is for.  The comment section is for comments, so I commented.  Your sort code is horrible.  The answer section is for answers.

Comment: You have not an array associated with the listbox nor there is any way to do it. You need to remove all elements from the listbox and inserting one-by-one again. The nearest you can go to associate your listbox to data is by using `SetItemData` and it is element-wise, not the full items contents. On the other hand, if you need to sort when clicking a button you can toggle the `LBS_SORT` style of your list using the `ModifyStyle` method. But I think it sorts alphabetically rather than numerically, may be it is not adequate for sorting integer values.